# Pronouncing the letter v in words like village, advantage,

Tags: pronunciation

I have heard at so many occasions, especially in Germany, that people - frequently including secondary school teachers and students - pronounce words containing the letter v as if the letter were a w, e.g. willage (instead village), adwantage (instead of advantage), etc. Does anybody have an explanation for this?

Comment: Germans don't have a /w/ in their language, so maybe they have a tendency to confuse /v/ and /w/. I wouldn't be surprised if /w/ was an allophone of /v/ in some dialects of German, but I don't have any direct evidence for this.

Comment: @PeterShor your comment led me to wonder if you were correct on that, and this added to what I'd already answered. According to Wikipedia it's not so much /w/ and /v/ that are allophones as /ʋ/ and /v/, but since /ʋ/ sounds like /w/ to many English speakers, this amounts to the same thing. I've added that point to my question, but it was your conjecture here that led me to it.

Comment: @Jon I doubt many English speakers would perceive [ʋ] as [w]. Nearly all speakers of German and any Scandinavian language (who all lack [v], having only [ʋ]) use it for [v] in English, and even native English speakers often use [ʋ].

Comment: @Janus: Even if [v] and [w] are not allophones in the standard dialect of High German, there are lots of other dialects of German which pronounce things differently. In fact, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W) says *" Modern German dialects generally have only [v] or [ʋ] for West Germanic /w/, but [w] or [β̞] remains heard allophonically for w, especially in the clusters 〈schw〉, 〈zw〉, and 〈qu〉. Some Bavarian dialects preserve a "light" initial [w] in words like wuoz (Standard German weiß [vaɪs] '[I] know')."*

Answer (score 8):

It's a form of hypercorrection.

In German, there is no /w/ sound, and the /v/ sound is produced from the letter *w*. Hence the translation, and cognate, of *welcome* is for example *willkommen* pronounced /vɪlˈkɔmən/.

This at first leads German speakers learning English to use /v/ (or perhaps /ʋ/) when they should use /w/.

Then they decide "ve vill have to do better", and strive to correct their /v/ to a /w/, but in so doing, they over-correct and end up using /w/ where /v/ would have been correct. They can even end up doing both "ve vill go to the willage".

Some other Germanic languages similarly either have /v/ for *w* (e.g. Dutch, *welkom*) or else have a *v* pronounced /v/ where the English cognate would have *w* pronounced /w/ (e.g. Danish *velkommen*).

Of course, English speakers learning one of those languages are liable to the equivalent mistakes on their part.

Peter Shor's comment above points to an additional pressure: [According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_phonology), "[ʋ] is occasionally considered to be an allophone of /v/, especially in Southern varieties of German". If true, then this would definitely be another influence, since [ʋ] isn't found in most dialects of English and sounds like /w/ to English ears (it does pop up as a pronunciation of *r* in some dialects, so e.g. Jonathan Ross—who has such a dialect—is mockingly called Jonathan Woss because to most other English speakers that's how his name sounds when he says it). I am only going by Wikipedia on the point of there being German varieties that have such a [v]/[ʋ] allophone, but it would certainly also lead to "willage", etc.

Comment: +1 in every particular, though what also happens occasionally is metathesis. Of course I don't have an example with v/w handy right now, but basically it's the same thing as with th/s, in things like *Elizabeth*, which so many Germans — including trained folk like newscasters, actors, and dubbing actors — pronounce "Elithabes". That occasionally happens with v/w as well. Which is to say, people are perfectly capable of producing both sounds, even within one word, they just swap them around.

Comment: Note that Dutch ‹w› = /ʋ/ is phonemically (!) different from ‹v› = /v/ and ‹f› = /f/. Danish (and Swedish/Norwegian) /v/ is always pronounced [ʋ]; [v] is completely unknown in these languages. [ʋ] is quite commonly heard as the realisation of /v/ among native (especially American?) English speakers, too, which makes me think that a [v/ʋ] allophony is not likely to be related to this. Many Scandiwegian speakers (who certainly have no such allophony) say things like ‘willage’, ‘wideo’, ‘wolleyball’, etc., too.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "Danish… v is always pronounced [ʋ]" well, except when I'm trying to speak it, which would be an example of what I said about English speakers being liable to the equivalent mistakes. (My Danish is very, very poor though, so I'm not an example of someone who is otherwise very capable but still makes mistakes, I'm just someone who visits every now and then and hence knows a few words, almost all of them not quite correct).

Comment: @Jon [ʋ] and [v] are very easily mistaken—and off the top of my head, I know of no other language than Dutch where they’re actually phonemically contrasted. So such a mistake is very easy to make, and I can assure you that no Dane will ever notice. [ʋ] and [w], however, are much more distinct. I seriously doubt Wikipedia’s claim that [ʋ] is used for /r/ by any significant amount of English speakers. Jonathan Ross, for example, has something that is definitely not [ʋ] (perhaps more like [ɣʷ] or something like that, though I’m not entirely sure exactly _what_ it is he says).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well, I've been told my *velbekommen* isn't quite right, but maybe it's just because I draw attention to myself by getting all the other consonants wrong too!

Comment: @Jon Or because _velbekommen_ (a very common mix between _velkommen_ and _velbekomme_) is not actually a word. ;-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I did say my Danish was bad, didn't I. But yeah, I do know the difference of the two on paper, that was just a erroneous portmanteau because I was thinking of both and failed to pick one over the other as I typed.

Comment: Idle question: In popular media, perhaps fueled by Bela Lugosi's performances, Dracula is often characterized as having the W-to-V problem ("I vant to suck your blood!"). Would that actually be plausible for a Transylvanian/Roumanian accent? I've heard claims both ways.

Comment: @keshlam Lugosi was Hungarian, (though I guess he also spoke at least some German, since he acted in Germany for a while). But, Dracula was (unlike the historical Vlad the Impaler) Székely and so his accent would likely have been closer to Hungarian than to that of most Romanians. As such, Lugosi's accent was correct precisely because it was **not** Romanian. Then again, some of Stoker's notes suggest he had changed his mind, but not fully transformed Dracula to Romanian (some political opinions changed after the first draft moved him from a typically-Székely to a typically-Romanian stance).

Comment: @keshlam Neither Hungarian nor Romanian has initial /w/ in native words (but both have initial /v/), so regardless of his actual geographical origin, the W-to-V mixup would be quite plausible.

Comment: Allo allo, Othervise I vill have you shot!